# Javascript Object Flip-around

Tags: javascript, object

I have a javascript object that looks like this:

```
{
    "Group 1": {
        "Aspect A": "value",
        "Aspect B": "value"
    },
    "Group 2": {
        "Aspect A": "value",
        "Aspect C": "value",
        "Aspect D": "value"
    },
    "Group 3": {
        "Aspect A": "value",
        "Aspect B": "value",
        "Aspect C": "value"
    }
}
```

Where the object can have many different groups and aspects, but the value for a **group and aspect combo pair** is always the same (E.g. there is one value related to the combo of Group 1 and Aspect A, so whether I reference them as Group 1 -> Aspect A, or Aspect A -> Group 1 should not matter).

Now, I want to change around the keys so that I have:

```
{
    "Aspect A": {
        "Group 1": "value",
        "Group 2": "value",
        "Group 3": "value"
    },
    "Aspect B": {
        ...
    },
    "Aspect C": {
        ...
    },
    "Aspect D": {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. _“Is there an easy way to do this?”_ - we are not here to suggest “easy ways” to you. You are expected to make an effort to try and achieve the desired result yourself, first of all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do something, like that:

```js
const src = {"Group 1":{"Aspect A":"value","Aspect B":"value"},"Group 2":{"Aspect A":"value","Aspect C":"value","Aspect D":"value"},"Group 3":{"Aspect A":"value","Aspect B":"value","Aspect C":"value"}},

      result = Object
        .entries(src)
        .reduce((r,[key,o]) => (
          Object
            .entries(o)
            .forEach(([k,v]) => 
              (r[k]=r[k]||{}, r[k][key] = v))
        , r), {})
        
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```